# LIBGDX- More than 16/32 Textures, is flush a good idea?

Tags: java, opengl, 3d, libgdx, flush

I'm creating a simple 3D game in LibGDX, together with my own shaders. I'm new to OpenGL so that is why I'm posting this question. Everything is working correctly for now, but **only** when I use openGL's flush() after each draw.

```
    camera.update();
    modelBatch.begin(camera);

    body_texture.bind(0);
    modelBatch.render(modelInstance_body, characterShader);

    modelBatch.flush(); //If I don't flush, the bind function uses the weapon texture for both (I understand this part). But is this the way I really should draw things in OpenGL?

    weapon_texture.bind(0);
    modelBatch.render(modelInstance_weapon, characterShader);

    modelBatch.end();
```

As my comment states, is this the way I should draw things in OpenGL? The way I'm thinking about openGL's draw part is:

- 1. Bind textures (Up to 16 and/or 32 units).
- 2. Draw the textures with the shader.
- 3. flush(), so the textures are drawn in the right order.
- 4. If there's more textures, start over (bind -> draw -> flush).
- 5. end(), Draws everything and the process restarts.

Correct me is this is the wrong way of thinking.

Comment: The `modelBatch` thing is specific to libGDX; there isn't an equivalent concept in OpenGL.

Comment: Don't modify the opengl context outside the shader. Use material attributes to specify the texture. See http://blog.xoppa.com/using-materials-with-libgdx/